# Why asynchronous tasks continue to be executed after node.js process exits?

Tags: node.js, async-await, event-handling

Below is a code example:

```js
export const waitFor = seconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))

const main = async () => {
    const test = async () => {
        await waitFor(30)
        console.log('after waitFor')
    }

    process.on('SIGTERM', test)
    process.on('SIGINT', test)
    await waitFor(30)
}

main().catch(error => console.error(error))
```

I start the script from terminal by running `node myScript.js` then
I hit `CTRL+C` in my keyboard the process exits. However in 30 seconds a message is displayed in the same terminal window: `after waitFor`.

I don't understand why `process.on` handler for `SIGTERM`/`SIGINT` events `await`s the asynchronous `test` handler. According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) `.on` does not accept an asynchronous function.

So does `EventEmitter` actually accept an `async` handler?

**EDIT:** it looks like Promise-returning event handlers are supported judging from the these official node.js [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_capture_rejections_of_promises), this mention should've definitely been featured more prominently in the docs. However, Promise-rejections will be ignored unless `EventEmitter` class is initiated with `captureRejections: true` option. The option is experimental as of node.js 16 version.

Comment: When you say "hit CTRL+C in my keyboard the process exits", did the shell actually give you back the prompt right after? Or the prompt appears after 30s and the "after waitFor" appears

Comment: The doc mentions about SIGINT and SIGTERM: "If one of these signals has a listener installed, its default behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit)." So your program does not exit when you hit CTRL+C, and actually waits for all scheduled callbacks to execute before doing so. Also, where exactly do you see the doc say that `.on` does not accept an asynchronous function?

Comment: @IAmDranged it can be seen in the docs (https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) that `listener` argument if of type `Function`, and not of type promise. When I say asynchronous I meant `async` keyword, that a function which returns a promise.

Comment: @EricWong first the shell gives back the prompt. After 30 seconds `after waitFor` appears at the prompt.

Comment: An async function remains a function. It is no promise - only its returned value is.

Comment: @IAmDranged an `async` function is still a function, you're right, but it's `await`ed in the example. This means that the caller of the listener doesn't simply execute it but `await`s, which is not automatic in node.js. I couldn't find the code which does the awaiting though https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5ce015ec72be98f064041d1bf5c3527a89c276cc/lib/events.js#L494

Comment: That makes me wonder... Because with the same code, as I tested on Mac zsh and `node:14` docker image, it only gives me back the prompt _after_ 30s, and I can only explain what's happening if that is the case...

Answer (score 0):

so i found this in the docs, I hope it helps
"Asynchronous vs. synchronous#
The EventEmitter calls all listeners synchronously in the order in which they were registered. This ensures the proper sequencing of events and helps avoid race conditions and logic errors. When appropriate, listener functions can switch to an asynchronous mode of operation using the setImmediate() or process.nextTick() methods:"
[docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) its close to the top of the page. I'm not sure if thats a complete answer but I hope it helps